# C# Entity Framework - Loading Data into a Form

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and C#.  I have a grid with my data in it and it works properly.  My objective is for the user to be able to double click on the grid and get into another form with the details of the record that they clicked on.  So I double click and it takes me to the new form.  I have the data binding source set to my EF data however the form displays no data.  I know I must be missing the command to load the data into the form.  Here is my command to get the data:

```
public Form2(int ID)
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  Entities CustomerContext = new Entities(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
  var customer = CustomerContext.Customers.First(a => a.id == ID);
 }
```

I have checked and var customer has all the correct data but I can't seem to get it into the fields.  The screen shows all blank data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because you are storing the stuff into a local variable? Maybe you didnt specify a DataContext for the new Form? Maybe... there are to many maybes to help you out

Comment: are you getting all the filtered data in the customer variable .? if yes there might be scope problem

Comment: @RandRandom  I added the line where I specified the DataContext.  If you could give me a clue as to a direction I could investigate, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  There were two items.  First, the format of my query was wrong and, second, I needed to map my query to the binding source.  Works like a charm.

```
public Form2(int ID)
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  Entities CustomerContext = new Entities(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
  var query = CustomerContext.Customers.Where(a => a.id == ID);
  CustBindingSource1.DataSource = query.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: You should consider disposing you CustomContext after you are done with it, to release the Connection to Database.